# Installing Redmine on Ubuntu 10.04

Tags: apache-2.2, ruby-on-rails, ruby, phusion-passenger, redmine

I'm having some issues installing Redmine on Ubuntu 10.04. I basically ran the following:

```
sudo apt-get install redmine redmine-sqlite redmine-mysql
```

It walked me through things and I configured Redmine to use SQLite 3.

Then, using Passenger, I got everything configured in Apache. I can now view Redmine by visiting `127.0.0.1/redmine`, as expected.

However, I can't log in. In my `/etc/redmine/default/database.yml` file, things basically look okay, nothing weird here:

```
production:
   adapter: sqlite3
   database: /var/lib/dbconfig-common/sqlite3/redmine/instances/default/redmine_default
#  host: localhost
#  port:
#  username: admin
#  password: password
   encoding: utf8
```

I then went to "Sign Up" on the home page, registered my account, then couldn't log in. I looked at the SQLite database to make sure that the account was created, and it definitely was. I cannot seem to get past this point. I followed [this official guide](http://www.redmine.org/projects/redmine/wiki/HowTo_Install_Redmine_in_Ubuntu#Ubuntu-1004-and-10041-using-Passenger). What am I missing? Whenever I try to log in, it tells me that it failed to log me in. If I modify the `database.yml` file to use the username and password fields, these don't work either. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After things are set up, log into Redmine via

```
username: admin
password: admin
```

Feel like a champ.

Comment: No problem, they should definitely put this in bold in the install instructions.